# It makes sense to consider oddness with respect a point which is not $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, symmetry, even-and-odd-functions

Let $F$ be a $C^1$ function and consider
$$G(x) =ax- F(x+a),$$
with $a\in\mathbb{R}^*_+$.
I need $G$ to be even.
Clearly, if $F$ is odd in the "usual" sense, so it is $G$. But, actually, I need $G$ to be even.

It makes sense to consider on $F$ a sort of "oddness" with respect to $a$ so that $G$ results to be even?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see how "if F is odd in the usual sense, so is G". Could you please show why?

Comment: $-G(-x) = ax+F(-x+a) = ax- F(x+a)= G(x)$.

Comment: If $F$ is odd then $-G(-x) = ax+F(-x+a) = ax-F(x-a)$ and that is not necessarily equal to $G(x)$.

Comment: @C.Bishop Your reply to my comment has an error, as noted by Martin R.

Answer (score 0):

As you evidently know, every function can be written as the sum of an even function and an odd function
$$g(x)=\underbrace{\frac{g(x)+g(-x)}{2}}_{\text{even}}+\underbrace{\frac{g(x)-g(-x)}{2}}_{\text{odd}}.$$

These two parts display a very nice symmetry, whether by reflection around the $y$-axis or reflection through the point $(0,0)$.

It would be a remarkably odd (pun intended) fact if this were useful but similar symmetry around any point other than zero had never been attempted.

The short answer to your question is **of course this kind of symmetry about other points than zero is useful and makes perfect sense!**

In consideration of continuity, differentiability, etc in the calculus you see the expression $f(x+t)-f(x)$ everywhere.  If we exploit this odd/even symmetry at the point $x$ we can write
$$f(x+t)-f(x)= \frac{f(x+t)-f(x-t)}{2}  + \frac{f(x+t)+f(x-t) -2f(x)}{2} .$$

These are called the *first symmetric difference* and the *second symmetric difference* and are obvious ways to exploit the odd/even split you are familiar with.

If you think  derivatives are important (hint: they are)
$$f'(x)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}t$$
then you won't be surprised the even and odd versions of the derivative are important:
$$ \lim_{t\to 0}  \frac{f(x+t)-f(x-t)}{2t} $$
and
$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+t)+f(x-t) -2f(x)}{2t} $$

You will see these kind of expressions in many studies, particularly in Fourier series.

A small sample of an "even" property and an "odd" property.  Note that both of these are much better using odd/even parts than just $f(x+t)-f(x)$.

**Theorem** (Dini) The Fourier series of a $2\pi$-periodic integrable function $f$
converges to $f(x)$ at a point $x$ if
$$\int_0^\pi  \frac{|f(x+t)+f(x-t) -2f(x)|}{t} <\infty.$$

**Theorem** (Khintchine) A measurable function $f$ is differentiable at almost every point $x$  at which
$$\limsup_{t\to 0}   \frac{f(x+t)-f(x-t)}{2t} < \infty.$$